# The closure of the irrational numbers on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> **Exercise**: What is the closure in $\mathbb{R}$of each of the following set:
>
> i) the set  $\mathbb{P}$ of all irrational
> numbers.

I have no idea on how to solve this question.

> **Definition**: Let $\tau$ be a topology on a set $X$ and consider $A\subseteq X$. If $x\in X$ is an accumulation point of $A$ if:
>
> $\forall \mathscr{U}\in\tau,x\in \mathscr{U}\implies A\cap\mathscr{U}$ contains another point other than $x$.

However I don not know how to proceed using the  definition.

**Question**:

Can someone show me how to solve this question?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then $b \in \mathbb{R}$ is in the closure of $A$ if and only if every interval $(b-\epsilon, b + \epsilon)$ intersects $A$, for all $\epsilon > 0$. Can you see how this is equivalent to your definition? Does it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $\tau$ represents the standard topology ,namely,  the open intervals in $\Bbb{R}$. So take any real  $x \in B \subset \tau$

Is $B \cap P $ contains a number other than $x$?

Surely yes! because any open interval $B$ contains both rational as well as irrationals, since they are dense

Comment: It must contain  rational numbers since they are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: so.............?

Comment: The the set of limit points are going to be $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Fine! actually all real are limit points

Comment: I thought the closure according to the way you are leading me is $\overline{\mathbb{P}}=\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{R}$, where the set of limit points is $\mathbb{Q}$, right?

Comment: Yea! its correct! $\overline{P}=\Bbb{Q} \cup P=\Bbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The irrationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and they do *not* form a closed set.

Answer (score 1):

Every rational  number is a limit point of the set of irrational numbers. Actually it can be shown that between any two rationals lies an irrational (and vice-versa).  You could do something like $x_n=\frac1n\sqrt2+q$, to approximate any rational $q$ by irrationals.  Thus the the limit points of $\mathbb P$ consists in all real numbers.

Thus, since $\bar S=S\cup S'$ for any set S, we have for the closure of $\mathbb P$, that $\overline{\mathbb P}=\mathbb P\cup\mathbb R=\mathbb R$.